# KSQL AVRO FORMAT ISSUE for Kafka Connect Elastic Search : org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: de******ense

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

Following Exception is being thrown for Elastic Search Connector:

```
[2018-05-07 11:40:38,975] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=elasticsearch-sink-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:172)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: de******ense
        at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.toConnectData(AvroConverter.java:95)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:467)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:301)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:205)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:173)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:170)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:214)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id -1
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic byte!
[2018-05-07 11:40:38,976] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=elasticsearch-sink-0} Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:173)
```

My configuration for `quickstart-elasticsearch.properties` :

```
name=elasticsearch-sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=de******ense
key.ignore=true
compact.map.entries=false
connection.url=http://127.0.0.1:9197
type.name=kafka-connect
```

I am passing the `key.ignore=true` but its trying to parse the key.

Code snippet from `WorkerSinkTask.java:467`

```
SchemaAndValue keyAndSchema = keyConverter.toConnectData(msg.topic(), msg.key());
```

The connector trying to parse the key but there is no key in the topics.

TOPIC Data sample:

```
{"EXPENSE_CODE":{"string":"NL1230"},"EXPENSE_CODE_DESCRIPTION":{"string":"ABC Company"},"NO_OF_DEALS":{"long":7}}
    {"EXPENSE_CODE":{"string":"NL1220"},"EXPENSE_CODE_DESCRIPTION":{"string":"XYZ Company"},"NO_OF_DEALS":{"long":308}}
    {"EXPENSE_CODE":{"string":"NL1210"},"EXPENSE_CODE_DESCRIPTION":{"string":"Alberthijn - Amsterdam"},"NO_OF_DEALS":{"long":287}}
    {"EXPENSE_CODE":{"string":"NL1200"},"EXPENSE_CODE_DESCRIPTION":{"string":"KLM - ADAM"},"NO_OF_DEALS":{"long":609}}
    {"EXPENSE_CODE":{"string":"NL1240"},"EXPENSE_CODE_DESCRIPTION":{"string":"EXIDS- Global Limit"},"NO_OF_DEALS":{"long":9786}}
```

schema-registry/connect-avro-distributed.properties

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9192


#schema.registry.url=http://localhost:9193
key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:9193
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:9193

# tried schema enable true as well for keys
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=true

config.storage.topic=connect-configs
offset.storage.topic=connect-offsets
status.storage.topic=connect-statuses

config.storage.replication.factor=1
offset.storage.replication.factor=1
status.storage.replication.factor=1

#offset.storage.partitions=25
#status.storage.partitions=5


internal.key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:9193
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:9193
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false
plugin.path=bin/../share/java # tried share/java as well
```

It's pointing to the correct schema registry URL.

Comment: The actual error is : 
`Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id -1
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic byte!` The messages you are receiving are either not a Avro message or they not serialized using Confluent serializer. Confluent follows the format of `[(Magic Byte) (Schema ID) (Data)]` check the link: https://docs.confluent.io/3.1.0/schema-registry/docs/serializer-formatter.html#wire-format

In your case it is not able to find Magic Byte.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Explorer. The data is being generated by KSQL. This is a topic for ksql's table which I am trying to read using connect. This topic has no keys and the exception is being thrown when it tries to parse the key because of its null. I disabled the key parsing in configurations but still, it's not working.  `ksql> show tables;

 Table Name        | Kafka Topic              | Format | Windowed
------------------------------------------------------------------
 DEAL_EXPENSE      | deal-expense             | AVRO   | true
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was when KSQL write to tables or streams. It will have the key as String and value as Avro.

If you change the configuration as shown below it will work

`vi etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-distributed.properties`

```
bootstrap.servers=lrv141rq:9192

group.id=connect-cluster

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:9193

value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:9193

key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=true

config.storage.topic=connect-configs
offset.storage.topic=connect-offsets
status.storage.topic=connect-statuses

config.storage.replication.factor=1
offset.storage.replication.factor=1
status.storage.replication.factor=1


#offset.storage.partitions=25
#status.storage.partitions=5


internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
internal.key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:9193

internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:9193

internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false

plugin.path=bin/../share/java
```

`vi etc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/quickstart-elasticsearch.properties`

```
name=elasticsearch-sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=deal-expense,emailfilters
key.ignore=true
compact.map.entries=false
connection.url=http://127.0.0.1:9197
type.name=kafka-connect
```

Changes are as shown below :

`key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter`